# Why isn't AppCode 3.0 is not letting me select Base SDK = iOS 7.1 with the lastest Xcode 6.0 beta?

Tags: ios, version, ios7.1, ios8, appcode

I've always been building and targetting my application for iOS 7.1.

<s>With a recent upgrade of AppCode to 3.0,</s> When I installed the latest Xcode 6.0-beta, I noticed something strange happening in AppCode. All the simulator devices were set to use iOS 8.0 despite my project settings not saying so in Xcode (value is set to `iphoneos`; which means `Latest iOS SDK`).

[image]

I try to configure the Base SDK in project settings, but I don't get a lot of choices:

[image]

What do I do here to set it back to iOS 7.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be, because you have set Appcode 3.0 to work against Xcode 6. And in Xcode 6 you havn't already downloaded the 7.1 simulator.

The fix is, to go to Xcode 6-> Preferences-> Downloads and download the Simulator 7.1. Then it should work (you of course also need a project with deployment target iOS 7.x)

Or: switch back AppCode to wirk against Xcode 5 in Preferences->Xcode on the right side you can switch back to Xcode 5.x.

Comment: Ach... yes, AppCode was automatically deciding on my behalf to use the latest XCode 6.0 beta without me even knowing (which is fair enough, really).

I actually really wanted to switch back to using my existing, stable XCode 5.1.1 environment. See my answer below for elaboration.

Comment: @Rudolf J: have you tried AppCode 3.1.5 with Xcode 6.2?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that AppCode was, as @brainray said:

> ... [configured] to work against Xcode 6.

Though installing the 7.1 simulator worked, it takes a long time, and at the end of the day the Xcode 6.0 environment is in beta and some tools are just about catching up: e.g. I  [couldn't run XCTests with Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta/issues/82).

The best solution I actually wanted it to run against my existing Xcode 5.1.1 installation.
You do this through `Preferences > Xcode` and configure it in the dropdown menu:

[image: AppCode Xcode selection]

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Simulator 7.1 in Xcode 6 > Preferences > Downloads
2. Don't forget to set Deployment Target to 7.1 - AppCode automatically updates list of simulators and devices according to your Project Settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've marked brainray's as accepted because of the more detailed explanation why the problem happened. I've had to restart AppCode for it to detect the simulator correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I have XCode 6, have installed the 7.1 emulator, and restarted appCode, but in the Base SDK dropdown I only see iOS 8.0 and I see no simulators listed when I try run tests; running tests then fails because of the architecture mismatch.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled AppCode and now its working. Hope this isn't going to be needed too often.